# Spring accessing a form

Tags: java, forms, spring

Im trying to access data contained on a form but I'm hitting a null pointer exception

This is my form:

```
<form:form action="dologin.htm"  method="post" commandName="loginform">
                          <content goes in here>
```

And the controller I am using:

```
@RequestMapping("/login") //login page
  public ModelAndView initLoginPage() {          
      Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      model.put("loginform", new Login());

      return new ModelAndView("login", model);        
  }

@RequestMapping(value = "/dologin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected ModelAndView logar(@ModelAttribute("loginform") Login loginForm, BindingResult result) {
    if(loginService.doLogin(loginForm)!= null){
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }else{
        String error = "Make sure to fill in all fields";
        return new ModelAndView("login","error",error);
    }
}
```

The Login class contains the same fields as the ones on the form (username and password)

Comment: Can you provide Stack trace and whole code for form and class?

Comment: Is loginService null, perhaps?  It's hard to tell without a stacktrace.

Comment: you'll need to provide some type of conversion, a propertyeditor for Login .. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html